# Render Html if Data is present into ajax sucess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have four link, On that every link we call ajax request and 
ajax gives sucess response in terms of html.

Expected result: On page ready (loading) trigger click function on first link if data is present then display first html else trigger second link and same for second and third.

```
<li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="abc('current')">Current</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="abc('forthcoming')">Forthcoming</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="abc('pending')" >Pending Listing</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="abc('recent')" >Recently Listed</a>
</li>
```

Onclick Function:

```
function abc(type) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('market/Equity/Ipo') ?>',
            data: {'id': type},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#ipos").html('');
                $("#ipoImage_div").show();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ipoImage_div").hide();
                if (data != '') {
console.log(data);
                    $("#ipos").html(data);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

if data is not exist then it will return following html:

`<div class="grid-box"><div class="coming-soon"><i class="sprite-img norecords-icon"></i><p class="txt-norecords">`

Currently there are no records found for IPOs

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Expected result: On page ready (loading) trigger click function on first link if data is present then display first html else trigger second link and same for second and third.

Comment: But I don't see any code that "triggers click function on the first link on page ready". Try to be more clear.